# Saving mail attachments to external drive

Tags: mail.app, email, attachments

I want to save certain incoming mail ***attachments*** to an external drive, not a whole folder or even a whole email.

I want to set up a ***rule*** in Mail that will automatically select certain regular attachments I receive and file them in a designated folder on a connected external drive, deleting them from Mail.

Clearly, Apple Mail's rules exclude any such capability and only allow filing in another Mail folder.

Can anybody suggest a simple way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You can run AppleScript as a rule action

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Why does it have to be a rule in Mail? This could be done with a Quick Action using Automator, too (see https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/use-quick-action-workflows-aut73234890a/2.10/mac/11.0 for details).